# Call winform function from html page?

Tags: html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a winform application that contains a c# webbrowser control.Webbrower control load a html page. On that html page I have a button. What I want is when click that button, it will call a winform function(function in Form1.cs for example). Is it possible? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [window.external](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx) object in your scripting code to access public properties and methods of the specified object. (See the sample in the link)

**C#**

```
public void Test(String message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="window.external.Test('called from script code')">
    call client code from script code
</button>
```