# Call a button/function in VB6 winforms app from html

Tags: javascript, html, winforms, function, vb6

At first I thought that this was possible until it came to my mind that I can't change the code of the webpage.
I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331146/call-winform-function-from-html-page) and that is exactly what I was looking for with the exception of, I am not the one who developed the html page.

What I want to do?
 - click/call/run a button or a function in VB6 using a "button" from an external webpage.

Anyone could give me an idea? It will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: VB6 does not use "winforms" but Win32 controls and custom GDI-based controls.

Comment: I'm not even sure the question you linked does anything like what you want.  The answer seems to have nothing but a "then a miracle occurs" comment in the button event.